# How to keep LongListSelector's current group name on top

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, longlistselector

I'm sure it has been asked before, but i cant find the answer. Is it possible using the LongListSelector control to always show the name of the current group? Just like it works in the People hub.

Comment: I dont think this feature is supported. You have to write your own control...

Comment: This is in the Telerik version, although it's for-pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a snippet. Please modify it as necessary.

```
var transform = llstItems.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
Point pointTarget = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
pointTarget.X += 5;
pointTarget.Y += 6;
List<UIElement> elements = (List<UIElement>)VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(pointTarget, Application.Current.RootVisual);
if (elements != null && elements.Count > 0)
{
    TextBlock textGroupedHeader = elements[0] as TextBlock;
    if (textGroupedHeader != null)
    {
        Main.GroupTitle = textGroupedHeader.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the control as part of the Windows Phone Toolkit

https://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit